# Append a specific character after each character of a string in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Thanks to advise me for the below issue:

I am using below query to fetch the value of a column:

```
Select OptionList = case  when isnull(AS_CIS_Code,'') <> '' then AS_CIS_Code   
   else ''  
   end 
from added_services
```

AS_CIS_Code column is of varchar(10) in added_services table. It contains values like 'AB', 'ABC', 'GHKIK', 'UYTIOPJ' and so on which represents different codes.

Now I have to select these codes after modifying the above query so that '_' is appended after each character.

Like it should be fetched as 'A_B_', 'A_B_C_', 'G_H_K_I_K_', 'U_Y_T_I_O_P_J_'.

How should I implement it? Using a temp table will down the performance for one column only, so should I use while loop or please suggest me better alternatives.

Comment: Can't you do it in UI?

Comment: No I have to do it in DB itself, I am sending this value using view to another application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string using a numbers table and the rebuild it using `for xml path()`.

```
select isnull(C.Value, '') as AS_CIS_Code 
from added_services as A
  cross apply (
              select substring(A.AS_CIS_Code, T.N, 1)+'_'
              from (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) as T(N)
              where T.N <= len(A.AS_CIS_Code)
              order by T.N
              for xml path('')
              ) as C(Value)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f89ea/1)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Input VARCHAR(100) = 'TESTING'
DECLARE @Pos INT = LEN(@Input)
WHILE @Pos > 1
BEGIN

    SET @Input = STUFF(@Input,@Pos,0,'_')
    SET @Pos = @Pos - 1
END

SELECT @Input
```

**Output**

```
T_E_S_T_I_N_G
```

**UDF**

```
CREATE FUNCTION PadStr(@Data VARCHAR(100)) RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Input VARCHAR(200) = @Data 
    DECLARE @Pos INT = LEN(@Input)
    WHILE @Pos > 1
    BEGIN

        SET @Input = STUFF(@Input,@Pos,0,'_')
        SET @Pos = @Pos - 1
    END

    RETURN @Input + '_'
END
```

**Output**

```
SELECT dbo.PadStr('TESTING')      -- T_E_S_T_I_N_G_
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Create Function Code_Pad
(
    @code varchar(max) 
)
returns varchar(max)
as
begin

Declare @coding varchar(max) =''
Declare @i int = 1

      WHILE(LEN(@Coding)<=2*len(@code)-1)
      begin
        Select @coding = @coding+SUBSTRING(@code,@i,1)+'_'
        set @i=@i+1
      end
return @coding
end
```

End of Function

```
Select OptionList = case  when isnull(AS_CIS_Code,'') <> '' then dbo.Code_Pad(AS_CIS_Code)   else ''  
   end 
from added_services
```

Answer (score 0):

May not be best solution, but works in one query using recursion

```
;WITH valCTE(Replaced,ToBeReplaced,Position)
AS
(
    SELECT CAST(LEFT(AS_CIS_Code,1) + '_' AS VARCHAR(20))
          ,SUBSTRING(AS_CIS_Code,2,LEN(AS_CIS_Code)-1)
          ,1
    FROM added_services

    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(Replaced + LEFT(ToBeReplaced,1) + '_' AS VARCHAR(20))
        ,SUBSTRING(ToBeReplaced,2,LEN(ToBeReplaced)-1)
        ,Position+1
    FROM valCTE
    WHERE LEN(ToBeReplaced)>0 
)
SELECT TOP 1 LEFT(Replaced,LEN(Replaced)-1) -- remove last _ 
FROM valCTE
ORDER BY Position DESC
```